# Adding JFXPanel to a JFrame. Why is it not working?

Tags: java, swing, desktop-application, gui-builder, javafx-2

I am trying to add a JFXPanel to my JFrame. I am using Netbeans and Netbeans' Swing GUI Builder. When I run it I do not get any errors and the JFrame is created successfully but the JFXPanel with the text does not appear.

Here is my code:

```
public class TestingFX {

  private static void initJFrame() {

    NewJFrame frame = new NewJFrame();
    final JFXPanel fxPanel = new JFXPanel();
    frame.add(fxPanel);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            fxPanel.setScene(createScene());
        }
    });
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            initJFrame();
        }
    });
  }

  public static Scene createScene() {
    Text text = new Text("Hello World");
    text.setFont(new Font(24));
    text.setEffect(new Reflection());

    BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
    pane.setCenter(text);
    Scene scene = new Scene(pane);

    return scene;
  }
}
```

Why is it not working? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I never used JavaFX, but I always heard negative result by mixing Swing with JavaFX, search for that on tihs forum, NetBeans forum ..

Comment: @Dorothy, Did my answer help you at all?

Comment: @Moonbeam Yes. I just implemented your code and it worked. Then I replaced the JFrame with my JFrame (NewJFrame) and added `outerFX.add(javafxPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);` and `Application.launch (Demo.class, null);` to my outerFX JPanels custom code. After some debugging I got it in the right order and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: @Moonbeam Sure. But if you'd a given me a day I would have done it. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you should read [Integrating JavaFX into Swing Applications](http://download.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/swing/jfxpub-swing.htm), and then refactor your code accordingly.

---

Try

```
public class Demo extends Application{
    private static JFXPanel javafxPanel;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                initAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    public static void initAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Swing application");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // Create JavaFX panel.
        javafxPanel = new JFXPanel();
        frame.getContentPane().add(javafxPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        // Create JavaFX scene.
        Application.launch (Demo.class, null);

        // Show frame.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void start (Stage mainStage) {
        // Add scene to panel
        javafxPanel.setScene(createScene());
    }

    private static Scene createScene() {
        Text text = new Text("Hello World");
        text.setFont(new Font(24));
        text.setEffect(new Reflection());

        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
        pane.setCenter(text);
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);

        return scene;
    }
}
```

---

When creating a scene, this example assumes that the code you've included is valid.

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to add JFXPanel to JPanel and this solved the problem for me, might help you as well

```
jpanel1.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
```

Comment: I had flickering issues when resizing the JPanel, this fixed them.