# put a JFXPANEL into a Pane

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I want to use a JFXPanel for a video player.
I use a fxml file for the design of the appplication. (not for the videoplayer itself)

```
...
<VBox>
      <Pane id="VideoEmbedded" fx:id="VideoEmbedded" style="- fx-background-color: #111111;" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS" />
      <HBox alignment="CENTER" prefWidth="600.0" spacing="8.0" />        
 </VBox>
...
```

I want simply to "replace" means fill the Pane("VideoEmbedded") with my JFXPanel.

```
//inside the controller
final JFXPanel JFXPanel_VideoEmbedded= new JFXPanel();

@FXML
private JPanel VideoEmbedded;
...
//inside the videoplayer function
VideoEmbedded.add(JFXPanel_VideoEmbedded); //this doesn't work
```

How can i add the JFXPanel into the correct position in the DOM-Hirarchy?

Comment: I don't understand why your `JPanel` is defined in your Controller class. Are you defining it in the FXML? If so, how are you managing the threading issues described in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/index.html)? (And if not, why is it annotated `@FXML` and how are you initializing it?) And also... your FXML file defines `VideoEmbedded` as a `Pane` but your controller declares it as a `JPanel`, which is obviously incompatible.

Comment: So it's really unclear (to put it mildly) what you're trying to do from these tiny code snippets. Can you explain what you're actually trying to achieve? Why do you need to mix swing components and JavaFX components?

Comment: okay my intention is to show a video in the pane. But i believe it is only possible in JFXPanels.i fought by defning it i have access to the Pane with the same fx:id in my fxml file.so i can say VideoEmmbeded take the JFXPanel inside of you so i can see it and it can play the video.(i just can hear the audio right now) In Jquery i would just do $('#JFXPanel_VideoEmbedded').appendTo("#VideoEmbedded");

Comment: That's not at all true. The JavaFX component that plays video is a `MediaView` (it uses a `MediaPlayer` and a `Media`). It can be placed anywhere you need it in a JavaFX scene graph, e.g. in a `VBox` etc. A `JFXPanel` is for embedding a JavaFX scene into a Swing application; it's a Swing component that can display a JavaFX Scene. If you don't need to mix swing and JavaFX, don't: you have a lot of tricky multithreading to work around. Just use a pure JavaFX application. [Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/media-tutorial/simpleplayer.htm)

Comment: so i can view the video in a normal pane?

Comment: Yes. A `MediaView` is a subclass of `Node`; it can be added to a `Pane` or any subclass (from your FXML it looks like you want it in a `VBox`).

Comment: can use Pane like Pane.setScene(scene); ?

Comment: Huh? No. That doesn't make any sense. Why don't you work through some basic JavaFX tutorials and see how the pieces fit together. The link I posted two comments ago has a complete class that displays a video.

Comment: Yes,but isn't that just inside Jframe which is a seperate window? i want it inside the pane.i can't find anything about that.

Comment: OK, again, why are you mixing swing with JavaFX????

Comment: I'm so sorry.Now i got it. You have said it before.I have to use MediaView for my Videoplayer.Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are mixing **Java Swing** and **JavaFX** (older technology and newer technology)
the JPanel VideoEmbedded is Java Swing  the JFXPanel JFXPanel_VideoEmbedded is JavaFX

see this thread [Adding JFXPanel to a JFrame. Why is it not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6710002/adding-jfxpanel-to-a-jframe-why-is-it-not-working) and the links above

Answer (score 0):

```
 panel.add(jfxPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

see https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/swing/swing-fx-interoperability.htm

or use JavaFX Scene Builder (Eclipse, Netbeans,...)

Comment: the easiest way is to use a visual layout tool like JavaFX scene builder

Comment: [More recent version of the link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/fx_swing.htm#JFXIP561) in this answer.

Comment: i actually used the scene for the fxml file ;-) i just can't insert a JFXPanel there.